# Add abline in ggplot2 which data from lm() result failed

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm, abline

I want to add abline() to the scatter plot , blow code only can return the scatter plot (the abline can't show). Anyone can help on this ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
model <- lm(mpg~ disp,data=mtcars)

abline_data <- data.frame(intercept=coef(model)[1],
                                 slope=coef(model)[2])

mtcars %>%  ggplot(aes(x=mpg,y=disp))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(data=abline_data,aes(intercept=coef(model)[1] ,slope=coef(model)[2]),
              color="red",size =6)
```

Comment: The line is there, but below the canvas.  Add ` + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,400))' and it'll be there

Comment: One point, abline_data has the data for the geom_abline statement, so you can use `aes(intercept = intercept, slope = slope)`, rather than pull the coefficients from the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your independent/dependent variables in the `ggplot(aes())` call to match the function (`mpg` as dependent on y-axis, `disp` as independent on x-axis):

```r
library(tidyverse)
model <- lm(mpg~ disp,data=mtcars)

abline_data <- data.frame(intercept=coef(model)[1],
                          slope=coef(model)[2])

mtcars %>%  ggplot(aes(x=disp,y=mpg))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(data=abline_data,
              aes(intercept=intercept,
                  slope=slope),
              color="red",size =6)
```

[image]